# Check if Python Dictionary Values within another Dictionary's Values

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I have two python dictionaries, and I want to return combinations of the dictionary keys if the keys do not have any values in common with each other.
Sort of like:

1. for i in 'a':
2. for j in 'b':
3. for i.items():
4. if any.i.items() in any.j.items()
5. continue
6. else show me someway to pair all combinations together

Lets say my code is as shown below:

```
a={'dog':['hungry','fun'],'cat':['ugly','old'],'fish':[1,2,'hungry',4]}
b={'raccoon':['ugly',1,3,], 'bird':[18,'hungry'],'cat':['orange','short']}
```

This would return

```
dog+raccoon, dog+cat, cat+bird, cat+cat, fish+cat
```

because none of these potential pairings have dictionary values in common.   If anyone could show me how I would do this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets:

```
from itertools import product
pairs = set()
for (ak, av), (bk, bv) in product(a.items(), b.items()):
    if not set(av).intersection(set(bv)):
        pairs.add("%s+%s" % tuple(sorted([ak, bk])))
print pairs
```

*Produces:*

```
set(['bird+cat', 'cat+fish', 'cat+cat', 'cat+dog', 'dog+raccoon'])
```

This can be more efficient if you have sets instead of lists in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can get it:

```
a={'dog':['hungry','fun'],'cat':['ugly','old'],'fish':[1,2,'hungry',4]}
b={'raccoon':['ugly',1,3,], 'bird':[18,'hungry'],'cat':['orange','short']}

result = []
for b_key, b_value in b.iteritems():
    for a_key, a_value in a.iteritems():
        if not any(x in a_value for x in b_value):
            result.append((a_key, b_key))
print(result)
[('dog', 'raccoon'), ('cat', 'bird'), ('fish', 'cat'), ('dog', 'cat'), ('cat', 'cat')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_shared(a,b):
    res = []
    pairs = [(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
    for x,y in pairs:
        if set(a[x]) & set(b[y]):
            continue
        res.append((x, y))
    return res
```

Basically test for any intersection between the lists (as sets) and then skip adding it if they have any intersection.

Also, if the list values are always going to be unique for that entry in that dict (seems so from the example) then storing it initially as a set saves you the conversion.